# Неизвестная ошибка с изображениями JPEG

Tags: android, изображения, jpeg

Доброго времени суток.
Такая проблема: пользователь не может добавлять изображение в приложение с галереи в формате JPEG. На компе с эмулятором всё в порядке. Но на смартфоне вылезает ошибка. 
Хотел попробовать через USB подключить, но не могу обновить драйвера ><
Вот так происходит обработка изображения:

```
try {
     imageTarget.setImageBitmap(null);
     final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
     final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
     selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
     int h;
     int w;
     if (selectedImage.getHeight() > selectedImage.getWidth()) {
     h = selectedImage.getHeight() / (selectedImage.getWidth() / 400);
     w = 400;
     } else {
     h = 240;
     w = selectedImage.getWidth() / (selectedImage.getHeight() / 240);
     }
     imageTarget.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, w , h , false));
                        addImageButton.setEnabled(false);
                        addImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        editImageButton.setEnabled(true);
                        editImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        deleteImageButton.setEnabled(true);
                        deleteImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Т.е. вы не можете логи девайса получить? Попробуйте через wi-fi его подсоединить. А ошибка наверное из-за отсутствия запроса на разрешения на ОС версии более 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня что то подобное было, у меня памяти не хватало для обработки, вылазила ошибка при добавлении изображения(хотя на эмул. было все хорошо). Попробуйте увеличить количество выделяемой памяти под изображение, а дальше сжать его.

Начиная с Android 3.0 можно попросить у системы выделять чуть больше памяти, прописав в манифесте просьбу:

```
<application
    ....
    largerHeap = "true">
```